# Multilinestring to shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have received the following file in this text format:

```
MULTILINESTRING((2513867.8515 5705794.4561,2512855.6784 5704240.0825,2511809.1121 5703060.1461,2507509.94
5707454.24,2513997.8033 5709971.3078,2513910.69 5709088.41,2513867.8515 5705794.4561))
```

How can I read this file and is there a way to convert coordinates from one projection to another using QGIS.

Comment: You have Well Known Text (WKT). Install WKT plugin for QGIS, create a new layer, paste WKT into layer, save as shapefile.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 6):

You can use Qgis for this. Layer -> add layer -> add delimited text layer

[image: WKT to point]

Then select Geometry definition as Well known text (WKT). Select first column as X and another as Y. That should creates you point layer i am not sure if it creates multiline too. If not just use Convert points to line(s) from SAGA toolbox.

[image: SAGA]